# PHP query date sort multiple query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have to pull data from a mysql data base but in date order. I am using a foreach command to get the data, but when the data is echo'd it is date order for each individual foreach result.

```
$userId = '29';

$sql="SELECT friendID FROM friendlink WHERE userId='$userId'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        foreach ($row as $value) {

        //echo $value; //echos name of the person

        $sql="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE userId='$value' ORDER BY date";
        $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

                $message = $row2['message'];
                echo $message;
                echo "<br />";



                } //end while

        } //ends foreach

} //end while
```

Can anyone recommend a better way to approach this. I need to understand how to get the data from the database in one go ad then sort the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using INNER join. Try the below code. I hope it works.

```
$userId = '29';
$sql="SELECT * FROM friendlink INNER JOIN messages ON friendlink.friendID=messages.userId ORDER BY date";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{

        $message = $row['message'];
        echo $message;
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks Fred. I never knew that query in mysql, that gets me a lot closer. Running that now it gives me the data in date order but I need to add a 'where friendlink.friendID = $userId.

Just tried a few methods, but i cant see where this would go in the query.

Comment: What do you mean by this ? `where this would go in the query.`

Comment: I used this query in the end, INNER JOIN was what I was after. 
SELECT * FROM friendlink INNER JOIN messages ON friendlink.friendID=messages.userId where friendlink.userId='$userId' order by date

Thanks Nadan, very appreciated.